# Why does this regex to find repeated characters fail?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to match any occurrence of two or more repeated alphanumeric characters. The following regex fails:

```
 import re
 s = '__commit__'
 m = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1', s)
```

But when I change it to this it works:

```
m = re.search(r'([a-zA-A0-9])\1+', s)
```

I'm pretty baffled as to why this is the way it is. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: seems you miss a ')': `m = re.search(r'([a-zA-A0-9])\1+', s)`

Comment: `\1\1` would mean that the character is repeated three times (The first capturing group, plus the two back references), which won't work since there are only two consecutive repeated characters in your example. The second one works because `\1+` means "one or more", which means that one can be matched.

Comment: @AliNikneshan thanks for the heads up, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line.

```
 m = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1', s)
```

You are using a pattern and two backreferences (A reference of already matched pattern). So, it will match only when minimum of three consecutive characters appear. You can do:

```
 m = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9])\1', s)
```

Which will match when minimum of two consecutive character appears.

However, the following one is much better.

```
m = re.search(r'([a-zA-A0-9])\1+', s)
```

That's because, now you are trying to match at least one or more backreferences `\1+`, that is minimum two consecutive characters.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense except for the third example you gave. If \1 refers to a capture group but a capture group hasn't even been defined yet (closed parenthesis hasn't been encountered) why does that work?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `\1` is a back-reference to any of the previously matching groups. So the original regex that does not work for you essentially means :

**Match alphanumeric strings that contain 3 occurences of the previously matchd group**. In this case the previously matched group `([a-zA-Z0-9])` contains a single character `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9`. You then have two `'\1` in your regex which accounts for two back-references to the previously matched character.

In the second regex the back-reference `\1` has a `+` in front of it which  means match **atleast one** occurence of the previously captured character - which means that the string confirming to this pattern has to be atleast 2 characters in length.

Hope this helps.